# Map user country from Facebook to Drupal

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-modules

I'm using drupal 6 and the module drupal for facebook. http://www.drupalforfacebook.org/

In my registration page when the user logins with facebook, the page autofill some data fields, for example, username, email, first name, last name, gender, etc...

In that page i have a combobox containig 240 countrys for the user selecting his country. I can gather the user's country name from facebook. But i have no ideia how to auto-select in the combobox the user's country, instead of doing "condition bruteforce" (239 conditions).

Does anyone got an idea?

Comment: Show county array which you have and show in which format you picking country from Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

`'#default_value'=>{theValue}`

See: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5